# Slow MySQL Query Over Millions of Records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Experts,

I need help with a MySQL query.  It involves two tables: 'usedcars' and 'counties'.

'usedcars': 16+ million records,

'counties': 3100 records

My query takes *minutes* to complete.  It's been hard to troubleshoot because MySQL caches the result so when I rerun the same query it comes up in under a second!

I'm sure the subquery is killing me so I could use some tips for an alternative.

Here's a sample:

```
SELECT p.make,p.total,sum(p.total) AS theCount, 
sum(p.total)/
    (SELECT sum(p.total) AS theCount FROM usedcars p, counties c
    WHERE c.FIPS IN (55009,55061,55083) AND c.statecounty = p.statecounty) AS MktPerc 
FROM usedcars p, counties c 
WHERE c.FIPS IN (55009,55061,55083) 
AND c.statecounty = p.statecounty 
GROUP BY make 
ORDER BY theCount DESC
```

I'm looking for the number of cars sold by brand in specific counties (FIPS) and also the Market Share (mktPerc) of that brand in the same sounties.

Market Share being: number-of-cars-sold-by-a-brand / number-of-cars-sold-by-ALL-brands

Here's the EXPLAIN:

http://1drv.ms/NqVuYT

Here is an example return.  It's giving me exactly what I want.  Just takes too long!

http://1drv.ms/1egJ0xm

Comment: forth field return always 1! remove c.FIPS IN... in your subquery. I think total of market is without filter.

Comment: Your subquery should be run only once, so it shouldn't be much of a problem. How much time does it take if you remove the subquery, and how much time does the subquery take by itself?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear what I was after.  I'm looking for the number of cars sold by brand in specific counties (FIPS) and also the Market Share (mktPerc) of that brand in the same sounties.  Market Share being: number-of-cars-sold-by-a-brand / number-of-cars-sold-by-ALL-brands

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Again, this is hard to debug and let you know query times becuase MySQL is caching results.  The initial query takes for ever but calling it again pops right up.  Without the sub-query it takes about 2 seconds.  The sub-query by itself takes only a few milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify with the following.

```
SELECT
      p.make,
      SUM( p.total ) SumTotal,
      AVG( p.total ) AvgTotal,
      AllBrands.TotalAllBrands,
      SUM( p.total ) / AllBrands.TotalAllBrands as MtkPcnt
   from
      counties c
         JOIN usedCars p
            ON c.statecounty = p.statecounty,
      ( SELECT
           SUM( p.total ) TotalAllBrands
        from
           counties c
              JOIN usedCars p
                 ON c.statecounty = p.statecounty,
        where
           c.FIPS in ( 55009,55061,55083 ) ) AllBrands
   where
      c.FIPS in ( 55009,55061,55083 ) ) 
   group by
      p.make
   order by
      sum( p.total ) desc
```

To help optimize, I would have covering indexes via

```
table       index
counties    ( FIPS, StateCounty )
usedCars    ( stateCounty, make, total )
```

Comment: The original query uses `SUM(price) GROUP BY make / SUM(price) w/o GROUP`. I don't know which one OP needs but the results will be different.

Comment: @pmascari, revised to get total market share sum basis too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have the following indexes:

usedcars  -> statecounty

countries -> (FIPS, statecounty)

Use the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE usedcars  ADD INDEX usedcar_index (statecounty);
ALTER TABLE countries ADD INDEX country_index (FIPS, statecounty);
```